# How can I change the title of my chat room?

Tags: support, chat

How do I change the title of my chat room?

I have created a new chat room on Stack Overflow, but I accidentally named it "Conservation" instead of "Conversation".

I want to correct this typo, but I can't find how to change the name of a room.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply click on 'info' at the top right part of the chat room:

[image]

Then hit 'edit' in the info page:

[image]

Comment: I let SE generate a chat room when it prompted that I should do so. And *room info* doesn't show this option. Do I not have the option because I didn't create the room? Is there an update. Hot to get SE to change the room name?

Comment: @GWarner I believe (though I'm not 100% sure), that generated rooms don't appoint you as a room owner, which is required to change the name of the room. Could you provide a link to the room you're talking about?

Comment: After some thought that is what I came up with. I expected coding would've already assigned me as owner since I clicked the link to automatically create it.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126549/discussion-between-g-warner-and-rockpaperlz-mask-it-or-casket  Personally, I think  the entire post with everyone's answers, everyone's posts would've been the right way to 'auto-create'. It ignored others' comments and answers, that was actually the biggest 'faux pas'

Comment: In lieu of this I created a room, the OP is there, and I would expect the others to join us soon.

Comment: I would like to reference others Answers and comments on the post with a link in the chat room? Possible?